# How to use createReprocessCaptureRequest?

Tags: android, android-camera2

I have a task take serial photos about 30 FPS with Camera2. It seems that a ReprocessCaptureRequest and a ReprocessableCaptureSession convinient for that, but I can't understand how to work with it and didn't found example.

```
InputConfiguration inputConfiguration = new InputConfiguration(mPreviewSize.getWidth(),
                    mPreviewSize.getHeight(), ImageFormat.JPEG);
          mCameraDevice.createReprocessableCaptureSession(inputConfiguration, Arrays.asList(surface, mImageReader.getSurface()), sessionStateCallback,mBackgroundHandler);
```

When I try create ReprocessableCaptureSession I get error:input format 35 is not valid

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62066375/7149454